# Efficient way to check if a list of random numbers contains a range from 1 to n

Tags: algorithm, range

If I have an randomly shuffled array with the numbers 1 to n, what is a good way to find that the array contains the range 1 to n (no repeats)? For example,

```
n = 6; [1, 3, 6, 2, 4, 5] => true
n = 6; [1, 1, 2, 4, 5, 6] => false
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make an array of size n, pass through your array and increment the position in the array with that as an index. If at any time the counts array has non 0 or non 1 value, you can stop. If you can't find the index, you can stop now since you know you don't have it.

Here's a quick Java example. In this example, you do not need to count at the end because anything that would cause a non-1 value would cause a failure during the middle.

```
boolean isRange(int[] arr) {

    int[] counts = new int[arr.length];

    for(int i : arr) {
        if(i < 1 || i > arr.length) return false;
        if(counts[i - 1] != 0) return false;
        counts[i-1] = 1;
    }
    return true; // if it wasn't, we would have failed by now

}
```

Comment: @yi_H You won't need to do that. If they didn't all have 1, it would have failed already. I realized that while I was making the method. I will remove it from the post, since it's unnecessary information.

Answer (score 3):

Sounds suspiciously like homework, but...

This is very simple using a Set:

```
/* Convert to your favorite language */

validateArray(a, n) {
  assertEqual(n, a.length)
  def s = new Set(a); // set with all elements of a
  assertEqual(s, Set(1..n)); // should be equal to set containing 1 to n
}
```

Comment: @Steve: I thought the point was to *verify* that the array elements were in the range 1..n with no repeats

Comment: the question says that the input array contains numbers 1..n. It says find that it contains the whole range (no repeats). Of course if this is homework, then the questioner has paraphrased, so the "real" question may or may not give the same guarantee about the input that the questioner does.

Comment: Mind you, the question actually says that it's a shuffled array with the numbers 1 to n. If it wasn't for the rest of the question, I'd take that to mean that it was already guaranteed that all numbers were present, and hence if the array is the right length then it must contain each number exactly once. So you're probably right to distrust the information in the question...

Comment: I'll admit it is a homework problem, but it is only a very small portion of the assignment. And it's not even my assignment! I was discussing this with someone earlier, and I asked only to see if other people could find a better solution than I had thought.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Gauss formula to precompute what the final sum will be:

```
final_sum = k * (k+1)
            ---------
                2
```

Do a linear loop over your shuffled list, adding the numbers as you go, and if your running sum is the same as your final sum, return true.

Comment: And what if you have `0,0,0,0,15`? How will you know the difference?

Comment: `1 3 3 3 5` has the same sum as `1 2 3 4 5`. How will you tell these two situations apart?

Comment: But you know what? It's thinking outside the box. That's worth something.

Comment: Does anyone say Gauss *invented* that formula, or just that he independently discovered it as a schoolboy? This article (http://planetmath.org/encyclopedia/KahunPapyrusAndArithmeticProgressions.html) suggests that the basic trick was probably known in Egypt in 1825 BCE, albeit AFAIK the Egyptians didn't write algebraic formulae.

Comment: Actually, the question as stated does say "If I have an randomly shuffled array with the numbers 1 to n" - that precludes the invalid inputs mentioned here.  Given that constraint I think the solution stands.

Comment: @Joe Valenzuela: No. If the input was a strictly "random shuffled array 1..n", the we wouldn't have to solve anything at all - since the answer would always be "yes". In reality, the "1...n" part simply states that all numbers belong to `[1, n]` range, but does not imply that all number are unique. `1 3 3 3 5` is a perfectly valid input under this statement of the problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're going to want to sort the array. Here is a link to some popular choices, http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithm. Personally I recommend bubble sort for a simple solution, and merge sort for a harder, faster version.

Once the list is sorted, you can check for repeats by iterating through the array and making sure that the next # is greater than the previous. Also, this can be added to the sort to shorten computing time.

Finally, check the first and last numbers to make sure they equal 1 and n.

Comment: Seeing as how sorting is `n lg n`, and there's order `n` solutions, I wouldn't recommend sorting it :)

Comment: Realizing that is probably isn't the fastest way, but will work in any language/platform.

Comment: @glowcoder very true. Wasn't sure how OP was actually going to do the question? Perhaps by hand. :b

Comment: I would not recommend bubble sort for any situation other than what it was invented for -- sorting records on a non-random-access memory drum in O(1) additional memory and optimal time. On more likely hardware, insertion sort is better-behaved and equally easy to code.

Comment: @SteveJessop potato potato. Personally I think that bubble sort is an easier concept for beginners. Not sure about better behaved, but insertion-sort can be faster. (Only difference between the two is inversion vs exchanging)

Answer (score 0):

If extra space is not allowed(typical constraint in an interview question), then you can sort the array first and scan the sorted array sequentially from left to right to see if every element is larger than its previous element by 1. The time complexity is O(n*logn).